# Size of the DOM structure

Tags: dom, structure

I found your topic that was dedicated to "size of the DOM structure".

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/dom

I would like to ask you if there are tools that can help identify useless DOM structures, so that can easily find non-mirrored nodes from an initially loaded document and delete them.
Also as an option, I would like to ask you which developers can help me with this task. How to find them, who can help me with this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Question needs specific explanation. What you mean by non-mirrored nodes.

Comment: Thank you for your message.
We are talking about an excessive DOM size, which in accordance with the recommendations of Google insight this should be reduced.  https://a.radikal.ru/a17/2008/a6/7f01107e24df.png